# Concurrent computing in dot net

Tags: .net, concurrency

How many way to do concurrent computing in dot net?
What are their pros and cons?

I googled and just found only a solution of using Thread class.
Thank you.

Comment: You should google again. There is also the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), and await/async starting with C# 5 - to name just a view more options.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? describing the whole concurrent topic goes beyong the possiblity of a forum. -> http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Joe-Duffy/dp/032143482X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336125393&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Parallel Programming in .Net 4
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71285/Introducing-NET-4-0-Parallel-Programming